# auto.arima with allowmean = T is the same as allowmean = F

Tags: r, time-series

Im runing `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package with the `allowmean = T` and with `allowmean = F` and get the exact same results - and both of them include an intercept.

Does anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong and how to resolve this issue?

following is a repreducable example:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
z=arima.sim(n = 101, list(ar = c(0.8)))
ts.plot(z)
```

Runing auto.arima with allowmean = F produces:

```
> auto.arima(z,d = 0,max.p = 7,max.q=0,stepwise= F ,allowmean = F)
Series: z 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.7275     0.4241
s.e.  0.0688     0.3012

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7118:  log likelihood=-126.52
AIC=259.05   AICc=259.29   BIC=266.89
```

which is exactly the same as with allowmean = T:

```
> auto.arima(z,d = 0,max.p = 7,max.q=0,stepwise= F ,allowmean = T)
Series: z 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.7275     0.4241
s.e.  0.0688     0.3012

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7118:  log likelihood=-126.52
AIC=259.05   AICc=259.29   BIC=266.89
```

I'll be thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bona fide bug. (Note that `allowmean` is a pretty recent addition - it's available in `forecast` 6.1, but not in 5.1.) I suggest you contact the package maintainer, Rob Hyndman, and point him to this question.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug. Now fixed on github: https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/b02c80f1f9cd6f9c0fa4f40ee3ac7919c2a1aaa9